# Шаблоны с++

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Подскажите, как в шаблоне template<int options> включать/исключать код в зависимости от значения options. Не хочется писать лишние шаблоны из-за небольших отличий.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Трудно сказать что-то более конкретное, поскольку очень мало дали информации. Могу как возможный вариант предложить часть вариативного кода заключить в другую шаблонную функцию или класс и уже ее/его специализировать. Например

```
#include <iostream>

template <int option> void  func();
template<> void  func<1> () {
  std::cout << "RES 1\n";

}

template<> void func<2> () {
std::cout << "RES 21\n"; 
}

template <int option> void func_gen () {
  func<option> ();
}

int main() {
  func_gen<1>();
  func_gen<2>();
}
```

Comment: Если я правильно понял, @mikelsv хочет что бы фрагмент кода вообще не компилировался. А специализированные шаблоны, как и обычные функции, будут скомпилированы. А вообще +1, хороший вариант.

Comment: Вышло адско, но похоже вышло. AddToList<options&OLIST_OPT_LIST>(el); В принципе так можно все опции раскидать. ) Здорово.

Answer (score 1):

Подойдет обычный оператор if. Пример:

```
template <int options> int getNumber() {
    if (options == 5)
      return 6;

    if (options == 7) 
      return 2;

    return 8;
}

int main() {

  int a = getNumber<5>();
  int b = getNumber<7>();
  int c = getNumber<67>();
  int d = getNumber<6456>();
}
```

Будет создано 4 функции ( ключ -O0):

```
int getNumber<5>():                   # @int getNumber<5>()
    movl    $6, %eax
    ret

int getNumber<7>():                   # @int getNumber<7>()
    movl    $2, %eax
    ret

int getNumber<67>():                  # @int getNumber<67>()
    movl    $8, %eax
    ret

int getNumber<6456>():                # @int getNumber<6456>()
    movl    $8, %eax
    ret
```

Попробуйте пропустить свою функцию через http://gcc.godbolt.org/ и посмотрите, что в ней остается при разных параметрах.

Comment: Не работает. if(options&OLIST_OPT_LIST){ use.OMAdd(el); } Код нужно именно исключать, так, чтобы компилятор его не использовал.

Comment: Покажите чуточку больше кода, что бы могли угадать, что именно там пишете.

Comment: А смысл? Вся проблема

<code>
template<int options>
class A{
  A(){
    if(options){
      anyname_class zzz;
    }
  }
};
</code>

Comment: Что значит исключать? if его исключит и он не будет вызываться (Но компилироваться все равно будет). Вы хотите #ifdef для compile time константы в шаблоне? Такого нету.

Comment: @mikelsv: Ну, смотрите же. Вы пишете как бы условие, проверяемое в рантайме (`if (options ...)`). Но поскольку значение константы известно в compile time, проверка будет выполнена на этапе компиляции — как раз то, что вам нужно.

Comment: @IronVbif: не знал, что константы оптимизируются даже на `-O0`.

Comment: Это не работает. Компилятор считает код неправильным и дальше не идет. Поэтому я написал свой генератор шаблонов. А вот сейчас решил вернуться на обычные шаблоны, но видно не судьба.